# Hilbert scheme of points on surface is a crepant resolution of symmetric product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, symplectic-geometry, moduli-space

If $S$ is a smooth projective surface, it is well-known (I believe first proven by Fogarty?) that the Hilbert scheme of points $\text{Hilb}^{n}(S)$ is a smooth irreducible variety of dimension $2n$. Moreover, there exists a morphism

$$\pi: \text{Hilb}^{n}(S) \to \text{Sym}^{n}(S)$$

basically taking a length $n$ subscheme to it's cycle-support. It turns out that $\pi$ is a crepant resolution of the singular variety $\text{Sym}^{n}(S)$. That is, the canonical bundle upstairs is simply the pullback of the canonical bundle downstairs. There are many nice resources outlining the proof of irreducibility and smoothness, but it is incredibly hard to find anything proving the crepant resolution statement!

1. Can someone shed some light on the crepant resolution proof? Maybe some intuition for it, or a link to a resource.
2. Just for historical understanding, who is this statement due to? I don't think it came from Fogarty's landmark work. Maybe it's too simple to attribute to anyone? I don't know.

Comment: Here is a sketch of a proof that Izzet Coskun once showed me (with some details very fuzzy and unjustified): first, note that the Hilbert-Chow morphism $\pi$ is 1) birational onto the symmetric product and 2) an isomorphism away from the locus of singular schemes (the general scheme of length $n$ is of course supported at $n$ distinct points, and is the unique such scheme mapping to its support because all singular schemes are supported on fewer than $n$ points). So to show that $\pi$ is a resolution it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Hilb}^n(S)$ is smooth which you know how to do...

Comment: ...To show that the resolution does not impose any adjunction conditions on the canonical bundle, note that the statement is local and can hence be proved for any $S$. So we take $S$ to be a K3 surface and use the fact that $\operatorname{Hilb}^n(K3)$ is a holomorphic symplectic variety hence has trivial canonical bundle, so there is "no room" for adjunction conditions (i.e. if $\omega_X(\sum_i a_i E_i) \subset \mathcal O_X$, then $a_i = 0$ for all $i$). I think the result can be properly attributed to Fogarty, but this is obviously a more high-tech modern proof.

Comment: @TabesBridges I do not understand your 'the statement is local' comment. Why can we choose a specific surface? Certainly, all smooth surfaces locally look like A^2, but I still don't see how this helps.

Comment: @CraniumClamp that is the main point that kept me from posting this as an answer; frankly I am hoping that someone better informed than I will turn up in this thread. As you alluded, I think this is somehow in line with the fact that we can analyze the blow up of any smooth point on any surface (or at least its effect on $K$) by looking at the origin in $\mathbb A^2$ or that more generally "blowups can be computed locally."

Comment: @TabesBridges oh ok, I thought I was missing something completely obvious. But the idea of using a K3 surface is very slick, +1 for the comments.